# Excel 2010 vbs, creating a named range causes an Update Values dialog box to appear

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vbscript, named-ranges

I'm using this code to create named ranges:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="B1065K16CN", RefersTo:="='1065-K-1'!$E$4"
```

A file requester box appears "Update Values: 1065-K-1"
when I cancel the box, the Excel Name Manager shows that Named Range was Created.

I'm creating over 800 names and this happened about 50 times.
I done see anything wrong with the ones that caused the errors and there seems to be no difference between the ones that didn't cause errors.

Any help would be appreciated, ( preventing the file dialog would be fine too, since the names get created anyway )

Comment: What's the rest of your code? I also have a macro that creates named ranges that doesn't throw an error. Perhaps it's something that's not exactly that line?